# Does Oracle own JRE and do I need a AWS account to use Corretto?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, java-11, corretto

Does Oracle own JRE(the technology) and do I need a AWS account to use Amazon Corretto? Also, what is the signature verification offered by Amazon on the Corretto download page? Do I need it?

Comment: *Is the JRE from OpenJDK/Amazon Corretto free for commercial use?* - Yes, it is. Check https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/

Comment: You have asked 3 unrelated questions in a single question.  Please don't do that.  Research each question individually (e.g. Google them) and if don't find answers that way, *then* ask *separate* questions.

Comment: *"Does Oracle own JRE"* - JRE is a trademarked term and Oracle owns the trademark.  Is that what you are asking?  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Amazon Corretto is a no-cost distribution of OpenJDK with long-term support.

See [the announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/amazon-corretto-no-cost-distribution-openjdk-long-term-support/):

> Java is one of the most popular languages in use by AWS customers, and we [AWS] are committed to supporting Java and keeping it free. Many of our customers have become concerned that they would have to pay for a long-term supported version of Java to run their workloads.

And:

> That’s why we are happy to announce the preview of Amazon Corretto, a no-cost, multiplatform, production-ready distribution of OpenJDK from Amazon.

Downloads come with a checksum (MD5) file, a signature file, and a signature verification file. These allow you to verify the integrity (via checksum) and authenticity (via signature) of the downloads. This helps you to ensure that what you actually download is what Amazon created. See [Understanding Signing and Verification](https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/jar/sign/intro.html).

Comment: No, not at all. OpenJDK, and Corretto by extension, have nothing to do with AWS, per se. It's a set of development tools that let you write Java for any environment that can support a JRE.